# How to I get the yoast plugin to create a sitemap with a different tld of same domain?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

Im new to wordpress

Currently I have installed yoast on my wordpress site and it generates a xml with the .com tld, but my website also comes in .co.uk and .ca - which basically the same site but different tld

How do I get the yoast plugin to also output a separate xml for the .co.uk and .ca domains?